# Rclone Mount Adding Non-Breaking-Space to Mac Command

Tags: bash, textedit, rclone

I have a script **mount-gdrive-encrypted.command**:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
rclone mount gdrive-encrypted:/ /Users/John/Documents/Mount -vv
```

When I double-click to execute this script:

```
Last login: Sun Jul 14 12:52:28 on ttys001
Johns-MacBook-Air:~ John$ /Users/John/Documents/mount-gdrive-encrypted.command ; exit;
2019/07/14 12:52:41 DEBUG : rclone: Version "v1.47.0" starting with parameters ["rclone" "mount" "gdrive-encrypted:/\u00a0/Users/John/Documents/Mount" "-vv"]

Command mount needs 2 arguments minimum: you provided 1 non flag arguments: ["gdrive-encrypted:/\u00a0/Users/John/Documents/Mount"]
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

`\u00a0` appears to be added at runtime, causing rclone to think my source and destination are one string instead of two.

I tried replacing it like this with no luck:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
cmd="rclone mount gdrive-encrypted:/ /Users/John/Documents/Mount -vv"
cmd="${cmd//\u00a0/ }"
eval $cmd
```

The rclone command works when run manually. How do I alter my script to stop this non-breaking-space from being added?

Comment: so `\u00a0` is a non-break space? Then it seems mostly likely your editor has "done you a favor" and used that, instead of a plain space char. Look at the options for your editor and turn off any web-help or formatting? Good luck.

Comment: I'm using TextEdit on Mac, and had already set it to "Plain Text". I'm not able to find any other settings that would add the non-break-space.

Comment: Almost certainly a typo in your script. Try deleting and re-typing the erroneous space. I frequently type alt-space by accident when I meant to type just a space.

Comment: Wow. I was about to get feisty and claim that I had typed and retyped my script (which I thought I had)...but you were absolutely right. Typing and retyping the space did the trick. I'm an idiot. Thanks so much.